# Is it ok to pass this to member?

Tags: c++

I have a class `Data`. That class contains 2 (or more) instances of class `OtherData`. Now, each instance of `OtherData` (stored as a member in class `Data`) has some data in common. I do not want each instance of `OtherData` to have a copy of that data they have in common. For example, `OtherData` could share an object of type `CommonData`.

Now, I decided to store the common data in the `Data` class. Upon construction, the instances of `OtherData` would then receive a pointer to the `Data` instance in order to be able to access the common data. I decided to do it that way to avoid the implementation of the class `CommonData`. It just seemed easier and shorter.

A short example:

```
// the class which contains the common data as well as the instances of OtherData
struct Data;

struct OtherData
{
    OtherData(const Data* data) : _data { data } {}
    const Data* _data;
    int getCommonData() const;
};

struct Data
{
    Data() : _data1 { this }, _data2 { this } {}
    Data(const Data&) = delete;
    Data(Data&&) = delete;
    Data& operator=(const Data&) = delete;
    Data& operator=(Data&&) = delete;
    OtherData _data1, _data2;
    int getData() const { return 1; }
};

int OtherData::getCommonData() const  { return _data->getData(); }
```

Now, from an instance of `OtherData`, I can easily obtain the common data.

I usually avoid passing `this` to a member, I hate circular dependencies (with that I mean an object containing another object and the latter having a reference or pointer to the former). However, it seemed so easy and I fail to demonstrate it's a bad design.

So, my question is: would you avoid such design, and why? Or do you think it is acceptable?

Comment: possible issue is with copy of `Data`: default one is "wrong" as no longer pointing on self.

Comment: @Jarod42 of course, I'll edit

Comment: Passing `this` to its member just add some dependency that we have to care, including: Not use `this` pointer until object is constructed, lifetime, ...

Comment: @Jarod42 so this code is simply wrong? Yet, it works fine.

Comment: @Jarod42 as I understand, the space for the Data instance is allocated before the constructor is run, so it should be fine.

Comment: As long as the member you pass `this` to only stores the pointer and doesn't try accessing members in `this`, it's fine.

Comment: One alternative is, instead of storing a `_data` pointer in your `OtherData` class (and having to worry about it becoming invalid e.g. after a copy), have your `Data` class pass `this` as a method-argument to any `OtherData` methods that need access to the common data.  This assumes/enforces that only the `Data` class will be calling those methods, and it's fairly robust in that the passed in `this`-pointer argument will always be valid.  (It may add a small amount of runtime overhead for the extra argument, but OTOH it reduces memory usage by not storing redundant pointers)

Answer (score 0):

This is a frail design. Copy or move around the initial `Data` (e.g. passing as argument by value) object and you've got mayhem.

#### Option A: disable copying and moving of `Data` objects

One way of dealing with this is to just disable copying and moving. Once a `Data` object is created it cannot be copied or moved, thus ensuring the pointers within `OtherData` stay valid. This is quick solution, but very restrictive, however it can be acceptable in some very specific scenarios.

```
struct Data
{
     Data() { /* .. */ }

     Data(const Data&) = delete;
     Data(Data&&) = delete;
     Data& operator=(const Data&) = delete;
     Data& operator=(Data&&) = delete;
};
```

#### Option B: use smart pointers

Whenever you've dealing with a resource that needs to be accessed from multiple objects, consider smart pointers - which implement RAII. Now you have to choose between `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`. If the `CommonData` needs to live as long as `Data` objects (no `OtherData` outlive `Data`) then you can use `unique_ptr`, else you need `shared_ptr`.

Example using `unique_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>

struct CommonData
{
    int a;

    CommonData(int a) : a{a} {}
};

struct Data;

struct OtherData
{
    OtherData(const CommonData* common_data) : _common_data { common_data } {}
    const CommonData* _common_data;
    int getCommonData() const;
};

struct Data
{
    Data()
        : _common_data{std::make_unique<CommonData>(1) },
        _data1 { _common_data.get() },
        _data2 {  _common_data.get() }
    {}

    // this field must be declared before any `OtherData` fields
    std::unique_ptr<CommonData> _common_data;
    OtherData _data1, _data2;
};

int OtherData::getCommonData() const  { return _common_data->a; }
```

Comment: I went with option A (I do not want to copy/move). What about @Jarod42's comment concerning using this before the object is constructed?